# gsub in R: replace space with double quotes

Tags: r, gsub

I have the following string where I want to replace the space with this pattern (including double quotes on both side) -  ","

```
s <- "-122.1817252 -119.4179324 -95.7128910"
s <- gsub(" ", "\",\"",s)
s
```

However I get the following output - with slashes

```
> s
[1] "-122.1817252\",\"-119.4179324\",\"-95.7128910"
```

How can I remove the slashes so that my output is  like

```
"-122.1817252","-119.4179324","-95.7128910"
```

Comment: It is for escaping.  If you print with `cat`, it will not be there i..e `cat( gsub(" ", "\",\"",s))` or use a single quote i.e. `gsub(" ", "','",s)` assuming that you want a single string (instead of any wild assumptions)

Comment: Assuming that's a vector, to get your desired output: `strsplit("-122.1817252 -119.4179324 -95.7128910", " ")[[1]]`